# Create Desktop Icon in Chrome/IE/Firefox using PHP (or HTML/JavaScript)

Tags: php

I want to create a Desktop Icon /desktop shortcut of my website. I have a favicon of my website and I want to use the same favicon as desktop Icon.

I have created a zipped file containing `shortcut.url` and `favicon.ico`, The `shortcut.url` has `IconFile="../favicon.ico"` set (both `shortcut.url` and `favicon.ico` are in the same folder in the zipped file), but shortcut.url is not taking the `favicon.ico` image.

For example, `love.zip` contains `shortcut.url` + `favicon.ico`.

This is my `shortcut.url`:

```
URL=http://www.google.com
ShowCommand=7
IconIndex=1
IconFile=../favicon.ico
```

PHP code to download the zipped file:

```
<?php
  $file = 'love.zip';

  if (file_exists($file)) 
  {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
  }
?>
```

This code is downloading the zipped file and when I extract zipped folder and extract `shortcut.url` it does not have `favicon.ico` image. Please tell me where I am making a mistake.

Or

Is it possible to hyperlink a desktop (jpeg) image to a website, not the `<a href>`

For example, I have a `test.jpg` image at my desktop, When I click on the image, it should open the desired URL.

Comment: try to change IconFile=../favicon.ico to IconFile=favicon.ico

Comment: @talsibony - Hi, thanks!, i have already tried the same, but no result , Please see image here - http://postimg.org/image/p2ex89oyh/

Comment: try to right click on the shorcut file and choose properties then change the icon file from there and then check what is the target by editing the file again

Comment: improved grammar and syntax